# Visual Studio Package build and DLLs in private bin path

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, msbuild, mef, package

I am using MEF to do a sort of crude plugin architecture. This is working well. However, when I do a deployment using the visual studio package/publish build tasks (which I am calling via NAnt/MSbuild). My unreferenced plugin assemblies are not being included in the package and so are not deployed.

Is there a way to tell VS/MSBuild to include these DLLs?

They live in /bin/Extensions.

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer in this blog post. It works perfectly: http://sedodream.com/2010/05/01/WebDeploymentToolMSDeployBuildPackageIncludingExtraFilesOrExcludingSpecificFiles.aspx

Basically here's the code I added to my project file.

```
<!--
    Added by RSL to deal with deploying the plugins folder
    Followed tutorial here:
    http://sedodream.com/2010/05/01/WebDeploymentToolMSDeployBuildPackageIncludingExtraFilesOrExcludingSpecificFiles.aspx
  -->
    <PropertyGroup>
        <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
            CollectExtensionDLLs;
            CollectExtensionViews;
            $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
        </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="CollectExtensionDLLs">
        <ItemGroup>
            <_CustomFiles Include="bin\Extensions\**\*"/>

            <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
                <DestinationRelativePath>bin\Extensions\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
            </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
    <Target Name="CollectExtensionViews">
        <ItemGroup>
            <_CustomFiles Include="Views\Extensions\**\*"/>

            <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
                <DestinationRelativePath>Views\Extensions\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
            </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
    <!-- //// End Rob's modifications -->
```

Comment: The task is CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn in VS2012, and it is imported by Microsoft.WebApplication.targets, so it must appear after that import in your project file.

Comment: Have you noticed that it copies the DLLs inside the Views folder as well?

Answer (score 3):

- Add the assemblies as links in the project where you want them copied: right lick on the project -> Add -> Existing Item -> select the assembly. Instead of just clicking Add, click on the arrow besides it and select "Add As Link"
- Select the linked assembly in the solution explorer -> open properties if it isn't opened:

  - Build Action: None
  - Copy to Output Directory: Copy always or Copy if newer

By doing the above the assemblies are still physically where you had them originally (I assume a references folder) and when you build those are copied to the bin folder.

Comment: Not quite what I'm after. I don't want them in the /bin folder. I want the private bin path (/bin/extensions) included in the deployment package.

Comment: @Rob add a /extensions folder under your project and do the same steps. It will copy them to /bin/extensions in the output.

Comment: btw the /bin shouldn't be part of your build, so you shouldn't have the originals there. You can define the itemgroup by hand similar to your solution, to apply what I mentioned above / simpler project file.

Comment: An oldie but a goodie. Still works. Even works with Jetbrains Rider. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer here for one approach: [Team Build 2010 - Third Party Assembly References not copying to output folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991422/team-build-2010-third-party-assembly-references-not-copying-to-output-folder/5992948#5992948)

Comment: Not quite what I'm after. I don't want them in the /bin folder. I want the private bin path (/bin/extensions) included in the deployment package.