# Visual Studio Build Definition - How to add additional (dll) files to build?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

We have an asp.net c# web site in team foundation server. Our project includes a number of 3rd party dll's, that are located under bin/ folders of all developers. We are trying to adapt a build strategy, by using build definitions in tfs.

We tried to build the project in a different server than a develeoper computer, and the build failed, since these dll's do not exist there.

My question is; how do we put those dll's to build definition?

Hope I made myself clear, since we are apparently novices in tfs build services :)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. Actually, we studied on it further and found a solution as follows:

- Put dll's into _bin_deployableAssemblies folder under web application (name of this folder is important)
- In the MSBuild Arguments part of the build definition, add /p:ReferencePath=""

That solved the problem. Thank you again in advance.

Comment: Adding the /p:ReferencePath="<PATH_TO_EXTERNAL_DLL>" did it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can either (#1) make these 3rd party DLLs available in the server that does the build, or (#2) check them in into the source control.
This is a discussion that has occurred several times in the past, in general the most advisable thing to do is proceed with option #2 .
Here are some further similar questions in SO, that might be useful to you:
[How to deal with external assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666597/tfs-vs2008-how-to-deal-with-external-assemblies)
[Team Build 2010 - Third Party Assembly References not copying to output folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991422/team-build-2010-third-party-assembly-references-not-copying-to-output-folder)
[Visual Studio Package build and DLLs in private bin path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152794/visual-studio-package-build-and-dlls-in-private-bin-path/)

Comment: The first link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add the files into the Source Control repository. In our solution we have a `\3rd Party` folder that contains all of the 3rd Party assemblies that our projects references.

```
\Main
  \3rd Party
  \Application
  \Modules
  \etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

In regard to Kemal Taşkın's response, great answer! Note that sometimes you need to leave a trailing '\' when using /p:ReferencePath=""

For example:
/p:ReferencePath="path\to\commondlls\"

For whatever some versions of MSBuild.exe remove the last '\'.

This also solved my problems using the TFS 2015 MSBuild Task's MSBuild Argument field.